# Changing the full scale deflection of an analogue volt meter

Tags: voltage, analog, dc, meter

I've bought an old pocket style (think of an old pocket watch) analogue volt meter and the full scale reading is 6V.

I would like to change this to 3V, however I have opened it up and there is no (multiplier?) resistor - or any resistors at all.

I've measured the coil and it is approx 52ohms.

How can I modify this meter to have full scale deflection at 3 volts?

Comment: The sensitivity is fixed by the coil resistance so not possible.  Must be older than me as my 1st galvo voltmeter was 200mV full scale using the smallest current range.  50kohms/V

Comment: Power = v*v/r, power = 6 * 6 / 52 = 0.7 watts dissipated in the coil. The temperature coefficient of copper is high --- 0.4% / degree C, so this meter is very temperature sensitive. Show a photo of back and front of the meter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach and understanding seems to be correct. Without a multiplier you don't have the option to reduce the multiplier resistor value to increase the sensitivity. With such a low value resistance it sounds like a moving iron type (although I haven't looked at these for several decades).

My old analog moving-coil multimeter was 20 kΩ/V and if yours had a similar mechanism the resistance should be 120 kΩ rather than 52 Ω.

If the meter has some charm and you wish to incorporate it into a project then you are faced with building a DC amplifier with a gain of two. At 6 V the meter will require a current of \$ \frac {V}{R} = \frac {6}{52} = 115 \ \text {mA} \$. This is too high for most op-amps so you'll need something a bit stronger.

52 Ω still seems absurdly low. Are you sure there isn't a short circuit?

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments. I thought that might be the case. Yes the coil does read approx 52ohms as your calculations look like the readings I'm getting here (cannot argue with ohm's law!). I thought of re-winding the coil, however the microcontroller I am going to use only has (I think without looking at the datasheet) 60ma output. What do you think?

Comment: I don't have an opinion. d:^) You're going to need > 6 V from somewhere to drive it. PWM a GPIO into an NPN transistor to drive the meter negative and you might have something going for you. Watch the 60 mA max. That might be for the whole chip.